# Link to CSV rendering as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-csv

I have a link in my rails application that should export CSV. But when I click on the link it reloads the page as html. I tried adding `response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=invoice.csv'` to the controller but that doesn't help.

#### controller

```
def index

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=custome_incentives.csv'
      send_data @incentives.to_csv
    end
  end
end
```

#### erb

```
<%= link_to 'Download to CSV', incentives_path(property.slug, format: :csv), class: 'btn csv' %>
```

#### update

I tried putting a binding.pry in the `format.csv` block and it does not fire.

Comment: You don't need those headers, just set type and filename: `send_data @incentives.to_csv, type: 'text/csv', filename: 'myfile.csv'`.

Comment: @CAmador That still gives me the same response.

Comment: byebug/log that format.csv, is the block really being run?

Comment: @CAmador It's not being being hit

Comment: set a new action just for the export, or comment out all the respond_to thing except the call to send_data

Comment: Also, is `incenctives_path(property.slug)` even pointing to `index`?

Comment: @CAmador creating the custom action fixed it

Comment: Glad to know. I think it was a routing issue, btw. Maybe your index action wasn't being hit at all. Check the log.

Comment: @CAmador Just checked. I was hitting that action, just not the `format.csv` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the routes are all in good order, have you [tried this way](https://www.codementor.io/victor_hazbun/export-records-to-csv-files-ruby-on-rails-vda8323q0) of including the `filename` like this?

```
def index

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      send_data @incentives.to_csv, filename: 'custome_incentives.csv'
    end
  end
end
```

It is also possible to [force a download link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12785972/4581953) if that doesn't work out.

Comment: It doesn't help.